# can image_proc/rectify nodelet process the image before image_proc/crop_decimate nodelet?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
image_proc/rectify can't public any camera_info message, but image_proc/crop_decimate can do it.
So, it seems that I can process a raw image before with crop_decimate and after with rectify, but not viceversa. Is it right?

Note: I tried to process rectifying before cropping with the following commands:

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone image_proc/rectify /image_mono:=gscam/image_raw /camera_info:=gscam/camera_info
rosrun nolet nodelet standalone image_proc/crop_decimate _x_offset=1 _y_offset=1 _width=639 _height=439 /camera/image_raw:=image_rect /camera/camera_info:=gscam/camera_info
```

But this latest nodelet gives me back the following errors:

```
[ WARN] [1349944791.310821026]: [image_transport] Topics '/image_rect' and '/camera_info' do not appear to be synchronized. In the last 10s:
    Image messages received:      288
    CameraInfo messages received: 0
    Synchronized pairs:           0

Node [/image_proc_crop_decimate]
Publications: 
 * /camera_out/camera_info [sensor_msgs/CameraInfo]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/compressed [sensor_msgs/CompressedImage]
 * /image_proc_crop_decimate/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /image_proc_crop_decimate/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /camera_out/image_raw [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/theora [theora_image_transport/Packet]
 * /camera_out/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription]

Subscriptions: 
 * /image_rect [sensor_msgs/Image]
 * /camera_info [unknown type]

Services: 
 * /camera_out/image_raw/theora/set_parameters
 * /camera_out/image_raw/compressed/set_parameters
 * /image_proc_crop_decimate/set_parameters
 * /image_proc_crop_decimate/set_logger_level
 * /image_proc_crop_decimate/get_loggers
Pid: 9120
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /camera_out/image_raw
    * to: /mbn_visualizer
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /image_rect
    * to: http://aldo-ubuntu:44836/
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Note: this is my node connections:
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45441/can-image_proc/rectify-nodelet-process-the-image-before-image_proc/crop_decimate-nodelet?/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-10-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see why you should not be able to run rectify first. The original `camera_info` topic is still available, so rectify need not duplicate it.

If you tried that and it did not work, please update your question with whatever error messages you received.

EDIT: looks like your topic names got mixed up with all the remapping. It looks like `/gscam/camera_info` was not passed to your `mbn_visualizer` node correctly.

It might work better to follow [the mini-tutorial for image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/image_proc) recommendation of running image_proc in the camera's namespace:

```
$ ROS_NAMESPACE=/gscam rosrun image_proc image_proc
```

This runs `image_proc` in the `/gscam` namespace, so it publishes `/gscam/image_rect` while leaving `/gscam/camera_info` intact. That is generally less confusing than remapping all those topics. The timestamps should remain unaltered.

You might be able to run the `image_crop` nodelet by remapping `camera:=gscam`. It seems to follow different conventions than the other `image_proc` nodelets.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-10-10**:
Hi @joq, I edited my post ading more information. I suspect that the origin of timestamp problem (showed in the Warning above) is due to "/camera_info [unknown type]" topic subscription. Have you got any idea to fix it? Thank you

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-10-11**:
Hi @joq, you're right: I need to specify the ROS_NAMESPACE=/gscam for rectify nodelet. If I don't do it and I merely remap input topic of proc_decimate, this last can't get gscam/camera_info. Below I 'll put the summay of the used commands.